# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

## I want to put that when someone writes a word from the black list he is timed out

> error *TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')*

```
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("1040666650535542876");
  const dateText = `<t:${Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)}>`
  const black = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `・logs-blacklist`)
  const i2 = message.author.tag
  var negro2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('2f3136')
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setDescription(` ${message.author.toString()} ha usato una parola blacklistata!\n **Messaggio**: \`${message.content}\`\n **Canale**: ${message.channel} - \`${message.channel.name}\``)
    .addField("Date", `${dateText}`, true)

  var negro = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('2f3136')
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setDescription(` ${message.author.toString()}, Non usare parole blacklistate o verrai mutato!\n **Messaggio**: \`${message.content}\``)
  let blacklisted = [ 'discord.gg','https://discord.com/invite', 'discord.com','https://dsc.gg/', 'dsc.gg', ];
  if (message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
    return`your text`
  }
  let utente24 = guild.members.cache.get(i2);
  let foundInText = false;
  for (var i in blacklisted) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
  }
  if (foundInText) {
    utente24.roles.add("1056224814588755998")
    message.delete();
    message.author.send({ embeds: [negro] })
    black.send({ embeds: [negro2] })

  }
})
```

Comment: You can't get a user from the cache by their `tag`. These are mapped by their `id`s.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `message.member.roles#add()` directly:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("1040666650535542876");
  const dateText = `<t:${Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)}>`
  const black = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `・logs-blacklist`)
  const i2 = message.author.tag
  var negro2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('2f3136')
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setDescription(` ${message.author.toString()} ha usato una parola blacklistata!\n **Messaggio**: \`${message.content}\`\n **Canale**: ${message.channel} - \`${message.channel.name}\``)
    .addField("Date", `${dateText}`, true)

  var negro = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('2f3136')
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setDescription(` ${message.author.toString()}, Non usare parole blacklistate o verrai mutato!\n **Messaggio**: \`${message.content}\``)
  let blacklisted = [ 'discord.gg','https://discord.com/invite', 'discord.com','https://dsc.gg/', 'dsc.gg', ];
  if (message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
    return`your text`
  }
  let foundInText = false;
  for (var i in blacklisted) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
  }
  if (foundInText) {
    message.member.roles.add("1056224814588755998")
    message.delete();
    message.author.send({ embeds: [negro] })
    black.send({ embeds: [negro2] })

  }
})
```

Comment: but if instead of putting the role how can I put the person to time out without using the function of the role